# How to migrade Spring cloud security oauth2 from Angel.SR3 to Brixton.M3

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

I just upgraded Spring Cloud from Angel.SR3 to Brixton.M3 and the Oauth2 security part now is broken. I've been stuck in it for few days.

Here is the Angel.SR3 code.

Application.java

```
package com.gaoshin;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.EnableOAuth2Resource;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Resource
@RestController
@RequestMapping(produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class Application {
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hi(Principal p) {
        return p!=null ? "Hello " + p.getName() : "Hello guest";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

ResourceServer.java

```
package com.gaoshin;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer 
public class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }

}
```

application.yml:

```
server:
    port: 9020

spring:
    oauth2:
        resource:
            userInfoUri: http://apie.pr720.com:8081/auth/user
```

Everything works fine. I can test with curl command below and it returns the right user name.

```
curl "http://localhost:9020" -H "Authorization: Bearer 2d48412a-2e5a-425c-acbe-ab2ab31295dc"
```

After upgrading to Brixton.M3, since EnableOAuth2Resource is no longer exist, I replaced it with EnableOAuth2Sso. The same curl command now returns error below,

```
{"timestamp":1448484209821,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"URI must not be null","path":"/"}
```

The log says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(UriComponentsBuilder.java:186) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriTemplateHandler.initUriComponentsBuilder(DefaultUriTemplateHandler.java:106) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriTemplateHandler.expand(DefaultUriTemplateHandler.java:100) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:556) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices.postForMap(RemoteTokenServices.java:138) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices.loadAuthentication(RemoteTokenServices.java:107) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager.authenticate(OAuth2AuthenticationManager.java:83) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:150) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

Comment: There is a pending blog post by dsyer about this, maybe it'll help : https://gist.github.com/dsyer/5b01276e9071c13492f7

Answer (score 0):

As Dave mentioned at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security/issues/81, the configuration is different.

The config prefix changed from spring.oauth2.* to security.oauth2.*